# If both cells begins with specific characters

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is there a formula in excel I can use to check both conditions in both cells before outputting true or false?

If A1 begins with Z AND if B1 begins with MN output false, else true.

Thanks.

Comment: Look at the AND function.

Comment: Look at ***the documentation of*** the `AND` function.

Comment: Thanks!! Both of you. Got it. I was missing quotations for Z and MN.

Answer (score 2):

Use this simple Formula,

```
=IF(AND(LEFT(A1,1)="Z",LEFT(B1,2)="MN"),"True","False")
```

or you can write in this way also,

```
=AND(LEFT(A1,1)="Z",LEFT(B1,2)="MN")
```

*Hope this help You.*